# How to make ajax postback in form with list of check boxes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I dynamically draw checkboxes in my form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { id="itemsList"}))
{
foreach (var lt in Model.MyList)
            {                
                <li>                
                    <label id="label">
                        <input value="@lt.itemId" type="checkbox" />
                        @lt.Title</label>
                </li>                        
            } 
}
```

JQuery function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#itemsList').ajaxForm({
            success: Saved,
            error: HandleError
        });
    });
...
```

But my action is not fired. Am I doing something wrong here? I am expecting that when I check checkbox make server call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am expecting that when I check checkbox make server call.

You should not expect that unless you've written handler for checkbox change

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#itemsList').ajaxForm({
            success: Saved,
            error: HandleError
        });

        $(':checkbox').change(function(){
            $('#itemsList').submit();
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`ajaxForm` will intercept submissions and send them via ajax.  But you need to trigger a submit for the ajax call to kick in.

Try adding:

```
$('input[@type="checkbox"]').click(function(){ $('#itemsList').submit(); }
```

You may want to refine the checkbox selector to something more specific...